# How to manage the permission on a newly installed managed package and a new profile

Tags: managed-package

I have installed a new managed package in Prod org called RDCC and have created a new profile testx.

How would I make sure that the profile is getting all the access needed to work on the new managed package that i have installed?

How to determine the permission that is needed by the users in that profile to make sure that they have access to all the objects and components using by that new managed package?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you'd better work with a permission set.
This way you can create a permission set that contains this managed package components, and add it to your current users without changing their profile.

Second, if you want to give access to all your package components, open the installed package:

Setup -> Installed Packages -> click on the package you want.

Then click the button "View Components"

Now you see all the components that where installed with your package, and you can add them to your profile or permission set.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If the package is licensed and if a user has a license they should be able to access all functions, the quickest and most painless way is when installing, select "All Users" and NOT "Admin Only". Since a user needs a license to access anything from the package this should not have any associated risk.

if the package is a site license read on.....

If the package ships with profiles, when installing select the third option. something like "custom, or select ....." and use the provided profiles to apply permission to your existing profiles.

***If you have not began configuring or using the package I would uninstall it and reinstall it and go through this process.***

If the package ships with permission sets, apply those to the users as required.

Short of the above, you will have to work with the package provider to understand what is required for the functions of the package in order to know what is needed to properly utilize each function. The more complex the package the riskier the process of manual permission assignment.